# Assembly code that deals with arrays and for-loops, and how to decode a map function

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, reverse-engineering

Here is my assembly code:

```
   0x000000000040114b <+0>:     push   %rbx
   0x000000000040114c <+1>:     mov    %rdi,%rbx
   0x000000000040114f <+4>:     callq  0x4013ab <string_length>
   0x0000000000401154 <+9>:     cmp    $0x6,%eax //expecting 6 characters
   0x0000000000401157 <+12>:    je     0x40115e <phase_5+19>
   0x0000000000401159 <+14>:    callq  0x4016a5 <explode_bomb>
   0x000000000040115e <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000401163 <+24>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x0000000000401168 <+29>:    movzbl (%rbx,%rax,1),%ecx
   0x000000000040116c <+33>:    and    $0xf,%ecx
   0x000000000040116f <+36>:    add    0x402740(,%rcx,4),%edx
   0x0000000000401176 <+43>:    add    $0x1,%rax
   0x000000000040117a <+47>:    cmp    $0x6,%rax
   0x000000000040117e <+51>:    jne    0x401168 <phase_5+29>
   0x0000000000401180 <+53>:    cmp    $0x3d,%edx // 0x3d = 61
   0x0000000000401183 <+56>:    je     0x40118a <phase_5+63>
   0x0000000000401185 <+58>:    callq  0x4016a5 <explode_bomb>
   0x000000000040118a <+63>:    pop    %rbx
   0x000000000040118b <+64>:    retq
```

On line <+36> is the following array table

```
0x402740 <array.3456>:          2       10      6       1 
0x402750 <array.3456+16>:       12      16      9       3
0x402760 <array.3456+32>:       4       7       14      5
0x402770 <array.3456+48>:       11      8       15      13
```

On line <+53> I see that I can avoid the bomb as long as %edx = 61

I understand that I need six integers from array table to add to 61. Such as 2+9+10+15+14+11 = 61

I understand how to find the address of the values. For an example:

x/w 0x402740 = 2

x/w 0x402744 = 10

etc

What I can't figure out is how to determine the function that would take a character i.e. 'q' and "map" it to a needed value such as 10.
Actually, I probably needed to reverse-map my 6 needed values. Like find what the value 10 is mapped from.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

UPDATE:

** I think the assembly code is something like this **

```
void function(char *str)
{
    const uint32_t *table = 0x402740;
    if (strlen(str) == 6)
    {
        uint32_t j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            j += table[str[i]];
        if (j == 0x3d)
            return;
    }
    call explode_bomb;
}
```

Comment: If you have made some progress on understanding the logic, you might do us the favor of commenting the assembly, or even including the C-version of what the assembly is doing, to save everyone the pain of mentally running the assembly themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key part is how each character in the string is processed:

```
and    $0xf,%ecx
0x000000000040116f <+36>:    add    0x402740(,%rcx,4),%edx
```

This looks like `table[str[i] & 0xF]` where the 0xF part is different than your C interpretation.

So it's the *low 4 bits* of each character that defines which index is used. This gives you several possible characters to use, since several will share the same low bits. So take your solution of 2+9+10+15+14+11, figure out what indexes those correspond to, and what characters you can choose for each index.

For example 9 is at table[6] is seems, so you could use `F` which is 0x46 or `V` which is 0x56, in ASCII.

Comment: Figured everything out. My C interpretation was off. I see my error (which was thinking the index is defined by all 8 bits, not the last 4). Thanks!